# transform rotate with position: relative

Tags: html, css

I have this css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px). 
{.art1{position:relative; 
bottom: 600px; left: 
1000px;transform: 
rotate(190deg);}}
```

And this html:

```
<div class="art1">Art</div>
```

The issue is that, in desktop, using `transform:rotate;` is sending the element off the page somewhere. As soon as I get rid of `transform:rotate` the element goes back to position. See [here](https://4309.co.uk) in desktop

Comment: Maybe because it has 100% width and rotates around it's center, which is moved 1000px right. If you add `border:1px solid red` to `.art1`, U can C the behavior.

Comment: Added it by can't see anything...

Comment: How is it supposed to look as result?
Also you can use `transform-origin` in css to pick the point of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set 
`left:0`

Most probably your left property, after element is rotated, means bottom, so you are moving your element above the display. It's because element is rotated with left property.